# How do I fix state error in flutter (bad element)?

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to pass this total amount as the fees of my payment gateway checkout page. But my debugger shows me this error in the image below. Please who has any idea what it means and how I can solve the problem? Thanks in anticipation[image]

Comment: Please provide the entire code instead of a photo or screenshot AND visit https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 0):

That is because there is no element in the List _cartItems. You cannot use reduce on empty List.

You can fix it by checking the List first

```
if (_cartItems.isNotEmpty) {
    return _cartItems.reduce((value, element) => value + element);
}
return [];
```